# Onsubmit in form does not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit, onsubmit

I have next form:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function submit(form) {
        var first_pass = form.find('.first_try');
        var second_pass = form.find('.second_try');
        if (first_pass.value == second_pass.value) {
            return true
        }
        first_pass.value = '';
        second_pass.value = '';
        first_pass.attr('placeholder', 'Пароли не совпадают');
        first_pass.css('border-color', 'red');
        second_pass.css('border-color', 'red');
    
        return false
    }
</script>
<form role="form" method="post" onsubmit="return submit($('#PasswordChange form'))">
    <h3>Редактирование пользователя</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control first_try" name="password"
               placeholder="Новый пароль"
               required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control second_try" name="password"
               placeholder="Повтор пароля"
               required>
    </div>
   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Отправить"></input>

</form>
```

This script checks whether passwords are the same.

But using firefox debugger i can't find that it goes into this method.

Is this problem with script? Or Is ths problem about declaring onsubmit handler?

Comment: #PasswordChange form ? where is this id?

Comment: @pedram it is a little bit higher, id of Modal Window, where this form situated. Is it important? In firefox console this commnad gives expected result as form.

Comment: yeah kinda important, check my answer below to find out

Comment: What is version of Bootstrap is used?

Answer (score 1):

**There was many problems:**

1. change `value` to `val`
2. use another name for submit function, it's kinda reserved
3. use `this` instead of `$('#PasswordChange form')`
4. use `var first_pass = $('.first_try');` instead of `find`
5. you forgot to write `else`
6. and you need use `event.preventDefault();` to stop refreshing page or submiting page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function save(form) {
        var first_pass = form.querySelector('.first_try');
        var second_pass = form.querySelector('.second_try');
        if (first_pass.value == second_pass.value) {
            alert('its ok');
            return true;
        } else {
        first_pass.value = '';
        second_pass.value = '';
        first_pass.placeholder = 'Пароли не совпадают';
        first_pass.style.borderColor='red'; 
        second_pass.style.borderColor='red'; 
    
        return false
    }
    }
</script>
<form role="form" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return save(this)">
    <h3>Редактирование пользователя</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control first_try" name="password"
               placeholder="Новый пароль"
               required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control second_try" name="password"
               placeholder="Повтор пароля"
               required>
    </div>
   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Отправить"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that I can't use just $('.first_try'). Because  I have other elements with the same class. on this page within different forms(like password changing, registration, everywhere we have to checks input passwords in the same way). Alse I cant use IDs instead of classes, because I expect the same behavior from the script working with defferent forms. that contains inputs with such classes. What can present as solution in the way?

Comment: Yes, see updated answer. you can use this `form.querySelector('.first_try')`

Answer (score 0):

**Use this :**

```
onsubmit="return submit(this)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that i need to pass jQuery object, as i expect to work with jQuery methods in submit method. Now i change it, but the problems still remains.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Please change submit function name because it is keyword so it is not use it. Also remove `</input>` next to submit button

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still presents.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitData(form) {
      var first_pass = form.find('.first_try');
      var second_pass = form.find('.second_try');
      if (first_pass.value == second_pass.value) {
        return true
      }
      first_pass.value = '';
      second_pass.value = '';
      first_pass.attr('placeholder', 'Пароли не совпадают');
      first_pass.css('border-color', 'red');
      second_pass.css('border-color', 'red');
      return false
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form role="form" method="post" onsubmit="return submitData($('#PasswordChange form'))">
    <h3>Редактирование пользователя</h3>
    <div class="form-group"> <input type="password" class="form-control first_try" name="password" placeholder="Новый пароль" required></div>
    <div class="form-group"> <input type="password" class="form-control second_try" name="password" placeholder="Повтор пароля" required></div><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Отправить"></form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not return anything if you don't need to cancel the submit action. Also you could use submit form event handler with jQuery `.submit()` method instead of hanler definition in `onsubmit` attribute.

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  var passwords = $('[name=password]');
  if (passwords.eq(0).val() !== passwords.eq(1).val()) {
    alert("Пароли не совпадают!");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post" action="/">
  <h3>Редактирование пользователя</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control first_try" name="password" placeholder="Новый пароль" required >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control second_try" name="password" placeholder="Повтор пароля" required />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Also I recommend you to use Bootstrap validation states instead of input's border style setting.